# Google +1 custom tag in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, google-plus-one

I'm trying to add the following custom element using TinyMCE...

```
<g:plusone size="small" callback="plusone_vote"></g:plusone>
```

I've added g:plusone to extended_valid_elements ( with two attributes ) and custom elements but it still gets removed when I click update on the code view window. TinyMCE init now looks like this..

```
        tinyMCESettings = {
            mode: "textareas",
            theme: "advanced",
            editor_deselector: "nomce",
            plugins: "paste,iespell,table,style",
            extended_valid_elements: "g:plusone[size|callback],script[type|src|defer|charset]",
            custom_elements: "g:plusone,~g:plusone",
            valid_children: "+p[g:plusone]",
            entity_encoding: "raw",
            convert_urls: false,
            content_css: "{/literal}{$tinyMCEcss}{literal}",
            setup: function(ed) {
                ed.onSaveContent.add( tinyMCE_GWO_Decode );
                ed.onBeforeSetContent.add( tinyMCE_GWO_Encode );
                ed.onGetContent.add( tinyMCE_GWO_Decode );
            }
        };
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the valid_children setting. You might need to add your tag as valid child there.

**UPDATE:** Modify your extended_valid_elements setting to

```
extended_valid_elements: "g:plusone",
```

this works (at least with my tinymce editor)

Comment: That seems to have worked, but only when I put content between the open and close tags. I can work with this.